# Is there a GWT Maven project structure, that doesn't mix up responsibilities?

Tags: java, gwt, maven

I am just getting started with GWT development using Maven as a build system.

I come from the Java + Flex world, so naturally I have client side modules and server side modules that are cleanly separated.

While digging into the best-practices og GWT and digging deeper and deeper, to me the default configuration of GWT projects feels more and more like a total mess of responsibilities. Especially when it comes to multi-module projects.

I did understand, that the convention states that server-side logic belongs in "server" packages, shared code in "shared" and stuff that is compiled to HTML+JavaScript by the GWT compiler in "client" packages. And all code goes to src/main/java. So far so good.

No matter how I try to see it ... to me stuff in the "client" packages is simply dead-code. Even if the java compiler compiles this to classes, the classes are never used at runtime and are only needed to provide input to the GWT compiler in the compilation phase. So even if it looks like Java, it's actually not and only looks like Java. It sort of feels dirty to place these inside the same jars as "live" code.

Wouldn't a maven structure like this make more sense:

```
/src/
/src/main/
/src/main/java
/src/main/shared
/src/main/gwt
```

And to have the java-compiler-plugin use src/main/java and src/main/shared and the GWT compiler to use src/main/gwt and src/main/shared?

Also it would feel a lot better if the build would produce two types of artifacts ... normal "jars" containing clases from src/main/java and src/main/shared and a second "gwt", which contains classes and sources of src/main/gwt and src/main/shared.

I wouldn't add a dependency to some mixed-up jar, but could decide if I want to import some GWT components or if I want to import some server-side functionality.

Next thing is that the GWT default is to place xml, resources and other stuff in src/main/java ... XML && Resources != Java ;-)

Or is there a real reason for all of this, that I simply haven't realized yet ... or do I simply have to start getting dirty and not worying about stuff like that?

Chris

Answer (score 5):

I came to the same conclusion a while ago, and created a couple archetypes to help get started: https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes ([announcement](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/codehaus-mojo-gwt-maven-plugin-users/vrLAcqp5oAg/discussion)).

Those archetype still have the `*.gwt.xml` et al. into `src/main/java`, because the Google Plugin for Eclipse didn't support putting them anywhere else (I've heard it's been fixed in a recent version but haven't checked yet).

Comment: I guess a really clean solution would be if the gwt-maven-plugin was extended to provide a custom packaging type of (for example) "gwt". Inside such a gwt-artifact I could have dependencies to jar and gwt artifacts and the default code location would be (for example) src/main/gwt. In this case I coudln't mix up GWT pseudo-jars and real Java jars, but I could reference real Java code from GWT. I woudn't have dead classes in my servers classpath. And anyone would see immediately that it's actually GWT code.

Comment: I'm working on such a thing (early prototype on my GitHub if you want it). You'd still not mix client and server in the same Maven module though (think about it: GWT needs both sources and compiled classes, so you'd need to call javac, ideally through the maven-compiler-plugin, with a different source path –easy– and classpath as for your server-side; there are also incompatibilities between some server-side components and the GWT Compiler or DevMode, so you'll want to segregate some deps as server-only and some others as shared; that's not _the Maven way_ of doing things, just split modules)

Comment: Hey ... I'd be glad to have the two things separated :-) So with your changes, would there be this setup with gwt artifacts and jar artifacts? This would be great. Just had a look at your github repo ... well this is indeed an "early prototype" ;-)

Comment: We're talking about auto-generating `<inherits/>` from Maven dependencies; one big unresolved question is where to put the `gwt:compile`? (in the `client` module with a special `gwt-app` packaging –similar to my archetypes–, or in the `server` module using, say, `scope=gwt` dependencies; the latter would at least make running DevMode easier, but the former is probably also needed for client-only apps)

Comment: Gee ... it would be really great if we could join forces. I would be glad to contribute to making work with GWT and Maven cleaner.

Comment: Feel free to start discussions on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/codehaus-mojo-gwt-maven-plugin-users, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-web-toolkit or https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-web-toolkit-contributors

Answer (score 3):

I have also tried to separate GWT client-side code from server-side code. The method I have used is to have a top-level project with 2 sub-projects, one for server-side, one for client-side. The top-level project has a pom.xml containing a  element for each sub-project.

The client-side project contains GWT java source in src/main/java and the rest of the webapp files in src/main/webapp. The server-side project contains just the server-side code.

Probably not the tidiest solution but at least there's a clearer separation.

Comment: I was just discussing a scenario in which I had a Sample Singleton in my server package and it was easy to call a method on this from client side code. So to me the cleanes soultion would be ho have 3 projects (client, shared, server) ... but I guess this would blow things up dramatically.

Comment: I never bother with shared, I don't like the GWT RMI, too confusing. I just use XML for client/server comms instead. GWT has xml handling.